# From the look of smartctl findings, is my SSD dying?

Tags: linux-mint, ssd, smartctl

My SSD is getting missed at BIOS sometimes from yesterday. Today morning though, it was completely gone out of the boot menu. I swapped the SATA cable and reconnected the power cable as part of troubleshooting process and during the process, one time it got itself identified at boot. I got into the OS(Mint 18) without further hiccups.

Right after I backed up the data I value, I ran a `smartctl` short test and found the following results. Could someone familiar with this please confirm whether this SSD in question is actually at the verge of giving up or is there any hope to fix the errors mentioned?

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-45-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron RealSSD m4/C400/P400
Device Model:     M4-CT064M4SSD2
Serial Number:    0000000011270313DEA7
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 10313dea7
Firmware Version: 070H
User Capacity:    64,023,257,088 bytes [64.0 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Mar  4 13:22:22 2019 +06
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  295) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   4) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   084   084   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       17
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       18432
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       9383
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       5270
170 Grown_Failing_Block_Ct  0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       9
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       483
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0033   095   095   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       174
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       164
181 Non4k_Aligned_Access    0x0022   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       1555 506 1049
183 SATA_Iface_Downshift    0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       25
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 Factory_Bad_Block_Ct    0x000e   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       49
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       9
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       1019
202 Perc_Rated_Life_Used    0x0018   095   095   001    Old_age   Offline      -       5
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       483

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 0 inconsistent with error log pointer 3

ATA Error Count: 0
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 0 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9381 hours (390 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 50 08 d0 34 2c 40   at LBA = 0x002c34d0 = 2897104

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 d0 34 2c 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00  42d+22:22:28.928  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  42d+22:22:28.928  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00  42d+22:22:28.928  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error -1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9381 hours (390 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 50 08 d0 34 2c 40   at LBA = 0x002c34d0 = 2897104

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 d0 34 2c 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 c8 34 2c 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00  42d+22:22:28.928  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  42d+22:22:28.928  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error -2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9381 hours (390 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 50 30 d0 34 2c 40   at LBA = 0x002c34d0 = 2897104

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 30 c8 34 2c 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 90 20 49 2d 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 03 88 48 19 2d 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 90 b8 38 2d 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 90 e8 30 2d 40 00  42d+22:22:28.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error -3 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9381 hours (390 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 50 80 f8 f8 b4 40   at LBA = 0x00b4f8f8 = 11860216

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 80 40 0b 7c 40 00  42d+21:42:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 40 80 09 7c 40 00  42d+21:42:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 40 00 09 7c 40 00  42d+21:42:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 88 00 f8 b4 40 00  42d+21:42:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 40 00 14 58 40 00  42d+21:42:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error -4 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 9380 hours (390 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  00 50 10 40 0b 7c 40   at LBA = 0x007c0b40 = 8129344

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 00 10 00 2e 17 40 00  42d+21:32:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 88 2d 17 40 00  42d+21:32:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 58 2d 17 40 00  42d+21:32:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 40 2d 17 40 00  42d+21:32:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 18 20 2d 17 40 00  42d+21:32:28.928  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      9383         2719472
# 2  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      9289         -
# 3  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      7651         -
# 4  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      6793         -
# 5  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      6785         -
# 6  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      6570         -
# 7  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      6171         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

PS. Perhaps its also worth mentioning that, I got stuck at a initramfs command prompt when the symptom first appeared. I then ran a `fschk` on the SSD and the problem seemed to be resolved for that time.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the title question, no, the SMART results by themselves are no cause for concern. Although your drive does have some unreadable sectors, it will reallocate them from internal reserves on the next write. Right now, `Reallocated_Event_Count` tells you that just nine blocks of the flash (corresponding to 9 * 2048 = 18432 sectors as shown in `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`) have been replaced by reserves so far.

If you don't want to wait until the currently unreadable sectors get rewritten by normal system operation, you can [manually write to them using tools like `dd` or `hdparm`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227823/251216), but that's certainly not for the faint-hearted (if you screw up while setting the write position, you'll lose some perfectly valid data).

However, the other symptoms you mention such as the drive failing to identify on power-on could really indicate that the electronics are dying. Most often, these issues are just due to problems with the PSU or cabling, so try plugging the drive into a different machine or swapping the PSU.

SMART tests usually won't tell you that anything is wrong with the electronics, they're mostly testing the actual storage medium, not the controller.

Answer (score 2):

The message

```
Self-test execution status: ( 121) The previous self-test completed having the read element of the test failed.
```

and

```
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      9383         2719472
```

suggests that your drive is failing and that logical block address 2719472 cannot be read correctly by the drive itself.
you will also discover kernel messages in the [/var/log/messages](https://superuser.com/questions/610425/find-log-files-of-linux-mint-after-system-turned-frozen) logs similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99553/does-a-bad-sector-indicate-a-failing-disk):

If you want to be near 100% sure, connect the drive to a different host and repeat the smart test. I've encountered drives not being seen by the bios because of old aged faulty motherboard but that worked fine in another system.